# On trying to install nvidia drivers: E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, package-management

I had purged all nvidia related drivers and dependencies on my ubuntu 18.04. However, while reinstalling the drivers I get the following error on running : `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-driver-440 : Depends: libnvidia-compute-440 (= 440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but 440.82-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.2 is to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-decode-440 (= 440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-encode-440 (= 440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: nvidia-settings but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: nvidia-prime (>= 0.8) but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libnvidia-compute-440:i386 (= 440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-decode-440:i386 (= 440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-encode-440:i386 (= 440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-ifr1-440:i386 (= 440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-fbc1-440:i386 (= 440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-gl-440:i386 (= 440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any idea on how to fix this? Thanks.

I think this might help:

```
$dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia
rc  cuda-nvtx-10-1                             10.1.243-1                                       amd64        NVIDIA Tools Extension
rc  libnvidia-compute-435:amd64                435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                          amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-440:amd64                440.82-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.2                        amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
```

These are my additional repositories:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ekc4R.jpg

Comment: You have some PPA connected. That is the problem.

Comment: @Pilot6 can you elaborate please? How do i disconnect the PPA?

Comment: Open Software & Updates and see what "Other" software sources are connected.

Comment: @Pilot6 https://imgur.com/oYDFGTu

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I solved it by trying to install dependencies directly. I started at the top and kept going until I found a dependency that would install.

Here's what I had:

```
 nvidia-driver-440 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-440 (= 440.82-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-kernel-source-440 (= 440.82-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-decode-440 (= 440.82-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-encode-440 (= 440.82-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-utils-440 (= 440.82-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-440 (= 440.82-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-cfg1-440 (= 440.82-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-ifr1-440 (= 440.82-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libnvidia-decode-440:i386 (= 440.82-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.2)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-encode-440:i386 (= 440.82-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.2)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-ifr1-440:i386 (= 440.82-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.2)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-fbc1-440:i386 (= 440.82-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.2)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-gl-440:i386 (= 440.82-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.2)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

First I tried installing `libnvidia-gl-440` (the first item on the list):

```
sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-440
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnvidia-gl-440 : Depends: libnvidia-compute-440 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This failed, but with just one dependency, `libnvidia-compute-440` listed.

Installing `libnvidia-compute-440`:

```
sudo apt install libnvidia-compute-440
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libnvidia-cfg1-390 libnvidia-common-390 libnvidia-fbc1-390 libnvidia-fbc1-390:i386 libnvidia-gl-390 libnvidia-gl-390:i386 libnvidia-ifr1-390 libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386 libwayland-client0:i386
  libwayland-server0:i386 nvidia-dkms-390 nvidia-kernel-common-390 nvidia-kernel-source-390 nvidia-prime nvidia-settings postgresql-client-9.3 screen-resolution-extra xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libcuda1-361 libcuda1-367 libcuda1-375 libcuda1-384 libnvidia-compute-390 libnvidia-compute-390:i386 libnvidia-decode-390 libnvidia-decode-390:i386 libnvidia-encode-390 libnvidia-encode-390:i386
  nvidia-352 nvidia-361 nvidia-367 nvidia-375 nvidia-384 nvidia-compute-utils-390 nvidia-driver-390 nvidia-headless-390 nvidia-headless-no-dkms-390 nvidia-opencl-icd-361 nvidia-opencl-icd-367
  nvidia-opencl-icd-375 nvidia-opencl-icd-384 nvidia-utils-390
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-compute-440
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 24 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 20.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 73.4 MB disk space will be freed.
```

This one was accepted. After it finished installing I retried `libnvidia-gl-440`, and then `nvidia-driver-440` and both were accepted with no issue.

So, just step through each of the dependencies and follow their dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! If anyone is interested, I got a similar error for Kubuntu 22.04 and an ancient NVIDIA GeForce GT 620 card, and your approach worked

Answer (score 0):

Remove the cuda repos repository. Most likely it breaks dependencies.

The `nvidia-driver-440` package from that repo requires wrong dependencies.

Comment: I removed the cuda rep but it still is showing the same error

Comment: Run `sudo apt update && sudo apt install -f`

Comment: `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.`    But it still wont solve it